# Custom UIButton subclass not displaying title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass

Let me start off by saying I am aware that this is a frequently asked question, I just can't seem to find someone with the same scenario/problem as me.

I am writing a music application, and I came up with a UI that I liked. It required a button with special functionality (past what can be achieved by the Custom Button type) so I decided to make a `UIButton` subclass. I used the following code in my subclass:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.activeState = false
    self.activeAccidental = UIImageView()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white:221/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.setTitle("Hello", forState: .Normal)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    println(self.frame.origin.x)
    self.activeAccidental = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, 20, 20))
    self.activeAccidental.image = UIImage(named: "BMICalcIcon.png")
    self.addSubview(activeAccidental)
}
```

However, when I add a button to my storyboard (and enter the custom class name in the field) my title, regardless if set in the initializer as shown, or in the attributes inspector in the storyboard, is not visible. This is my first major project in swift, so I am not sure entirely what the problem is.

Code when `ImageView` moved to `initWithCoder`

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.activeState = false
    self.activeAccidental = UIImageView()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.activeAccidental = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, 20, 20))
    self.activeAccidental.image = UIImage(named: "BMICalcIcon.png")
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white:221/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.setTitle("Hello", forState: .Normal)
    self.addSubview(activeAccidental)
}
```

Comment: Your layer's background color and your title are both white. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I must have copied the code wrong, I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the problem is putting the code for adding the image view in layoutSubviews -- that's not a good place anyway, since it can be called multiple times, which will cause you to add multiple image views. If you move that code into your initWithCoder method, it will work properly. Here's the test class I made,

```
import UIKit

class RDButton: UIButton {

    var activeState: Bool
    var activeAccidental: UIImageView

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.activeState = false
        self.activeAccidental = UIImageView()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.activeAccidental = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, 20, 20))
        self.activeAccidental.image = UIImage(named: "img.jpg")
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white:221/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.setTitle("Hello", forState: .Normal)
        self.addSubview(activeAccidental)

    }
}
```

Comment: Should I be leaving any code in the layoutSubviews() method?

Comment: I just tried moving the code into the initWithCoder() method. No dice.

Comment: @ericmark26, That's strange, I copied your code, and did what I said, and it worked for me. Are you seeing your image?

Comment: Actually, the entire reason I put the code in the layoutSubviews() method in the first place is because `self.bounds.origin.x` and `.y` both return 0 in the init method, while they return actual values in the layoutSubviews() method.

Comment: @ericmark26, isn't self.bounds.origin (0,0) anyway? It usually is.

Comment: Yeah, but so is `self.frame.origin.x` and `.y`
Also, using .bounds allows you to set the location of the subview relative to the location of the superview.

Comment: @ericmark26, So what? You're not using self.frame at all in your code. I've posted my sample code; it works fine. Maybe try commenting out the line where you set the image of the image view to see if the image is the problem (I don't know why it would be, but that appears to be the only difference between my code and yours).

Comment: Then may I ask what your settings are in the storyboard for the button you added?

Comment: @ericmark26, I added constraints to center it in the superview, and gave it width and height constraints of 80. Changed the class to RDButton.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Turns out deleting the code from layoutSubviews() wasn't enough, I needed to remove the method, probably to prevent the code from resetting all the subviews (including the title). Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: BTW, if you need to put code in a method where the frame will be correct, I like to override didMoveToSuperview(). It's only called once, and the frames are correct there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I implement active states, where do you suggest I write the code for re-rendering the button?

Comment: @ericmark26, I'm not sure, since I don't know what you're doing with that, but you could override the setter for activeState, and put the code there.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a huge help.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe add `[super layoutSubviews];`
I had the same problem because I forgot to add this piece of line. After that you can add the code you want.

Comment: Great answer, that made me crazy for half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when the current view controller (containing the custom button) was started with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` from a queue other than the main. To fix this, just call the method within main thread. For example:

```
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    ...
    func doTask() {
        let myTask = MyTask()
        myTask.perform( {
            Dispatch.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```