# Title not showing for custom UIButton class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a custom UIButton class which features a round frame. The problem is although I set up the title property of each button from the storyboard they are not showing. I end up with round buttons with no titles showing inside them. I am trying to do a keypad like the one in default iOS passcode screen. My main view background color is not white and I am not using any background images for the buttons. Here is my code for the custom UIButton class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyOwnButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(33.0)
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had same issue, this answer worked for me: [Custom UIButton subclass not displaying title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857994/custom-uibutton-subclass-not-displaying-title)

Add `super.layoutSubviews()` after you override the function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your UIButton's class as your custom class in storyboard??

Comment: Yes. Done for all, if I hadn't, I wouldn't see round buttons.

Comment: @basser Try to set it in code as  self.titleLabel?.text = "YOUR_TITLE"

Comment: It doesn't work Also, it will name all the buttons the same. I need each button to have different title like 0,1,2,3...,9

Comment: @basser Then why don't you write a constructor with parameter which will take String for title and the set it.

Comment: I am not creating the buttons with code. I am making them on the storyboard. I just don't understand why title is not showing even though I set the title in the storyboard for each button. Plus, it is not even working in code if I use self.setTitle("title", .Normal)

Comment: If possible can you send me your code so that I can try at might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the things in `init` method and check.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyOwnButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(33.0)
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


}
```

Comment: none of the buttons appear on the screen that way :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for **Swift 4**

```
import UIKit

class MyOwnButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect){
       super.init(frame: frame)

        commonSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonSetup()
    }

    private func commonSetup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 33.0)
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the title of the button, simply:

[button sizeToFit];